# ¿Por qué "katiuska" es una bota de material impermeable?

Tags: etimología, historia, palabras-raras, ropa

El DLE recoge [**katiuska**](https://dle.rae.es/katiuska) como:

> Del n. p. ruso *Katjuša*, hipocorístico de *Katja*, y este de *Ekaterina* 'Catalina'.
>
> 1. f. Bota de material impermeable, de caña alta, para proteger del agua.

Lo que da una clara explicación de la etimología de la palabra, pero no de la relación entre la palabra y su significado.  ¿Cómo llegó un nombre propio ruso modificado a designar unas botas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botas_de_goma) da una explicación:

> El nombre "Katiuska" proviene de una famosa zarzuela (género de teatro lírico) escrita por Emilio González del Castillo y Manuel Martí Alonso y música compuesta por Pablo Sorozábal, que se estrenó en el Teatro Victoria de Barcelona el 27 de enero de 1931. Dicha obra musical, llamada "Katiuska, la mujer rusa" donde la protagonista llevaba unas botas de media caña, fue popularizada y debido al hecho que muchas mujeres pedían en las zapatería botas como las de Katiuska se les empezó a llamar así.

Comment: Indudablemente existe la zarzuela Katiuska (con distintas variaciones en el nombre en distintos momentos) y efectivamente fue un gran éxito cuando modificaron el segundo acto. Pero no encuentro una referencia (salvo la del autor del artículo de Wikipedia) a la parte clave de la respuesta: **"debido al hecho que muchas mujeres pedían en las zapatería botas como las de Katiuska se les empezó a llamar así."**  Por supuesto que  eso haya sido así, pero sin una referencia ...